# Access Property of a Nested Record

Tags: react-admin, api-platform.com

I'm using React-Admin 3.5.0 with [api-platform/admin](https://github.com/api-platform/admin) 2.1.1.

I have a custom list for one of my resources.
The resource has a `title` and an `author`. The author has several properties, one of which is `username`.

Following the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html), I tried to display the username of the author in my list like this:

```
export const MyList = (props) =>
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="title" />
            <TextField source="author.username" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
```

This does not work. The field for `author.username` is empty.

I investigated a bit and found that the record only contains the ID of the author:

```
record:
    ...
    title: "abcde"
    author: "/users/1"
```

The response from the server however does contain the username property:

```
0: {
    ...,
    "title": "abcde",
    "author": {
        "@id": "/users/1",
        "username": "Test"
    }
},
...
```

Is there any nice way to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this on api-platform admin source code:

> Replace embedded objects by their IRIs, and store the object itself in
>   the cache to reuse without issuing new HTTP requests.

And right below:

```
document[key] = document[key]['@id'];
```

https://github.com/api-platform/admin/blob/ba0630083f28eaa8806bc1da4613677924604a52/src/hydra/dataProvider.js#L75

This behavior came from this pull request:

https://github.com/api-platform/admin/pull/96

To display author fields, you will need to use a ReferenceField for each one of them:

```
export const MyList = (props) =>
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="title" />
            <ReferenceField source="author" reference="users">
                <TextField source="username"/>
            </ReferenceField>

            <ReferenceField source="author" reference="users" link={false}>
                <TextField source="email"/>
            </ReferenceField>
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
```

Doing it will make the author fields link to the author page. You can disable this passing link={false} on the ReferenceField, like on the second author field above

React admin will pack all those author reference requests into a single one, so even if api-platform data provider woun't do it's cache promise, you will endup with only one http request.

Note: You must add a `<Resource>` for the reference resource - react-admin needs it to fetch the reference data. You can omit the list prop in this reference if you want to hide it in the sidebar menu.

Answer (score 1):

version 2.2 should support nested/embedded objects:

See
https://api-platform.com/docs/admin/handling-relations/#display-a-field-of-an-embedded-relation

I tried it. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me...

```
import {
    fetchHydra
    HydraAdmin,
    hydraDataProvider as baseHydraDataProvider,
} from "@api-platform/admin";

const dataProvider = baseHydraDataProvider(
    entrypoint,
    fetchHydra,
    apiDocumentationParser,
    true // use embedded!
);

export default () => (
    <HydraAdmin
        dataProvider={dataProvider} authProvider={authProvider} entrypoint={entrypoint} i18nProvider={i18nProvider}>
        <ResourceGuesser name={"users"} list={UserList} icon={UserIcon}/>
         ....
    </HydraAdmin>
```

[image: record input v.s. transmitted input]

**How to debug**

Log the converted record data into your console (this causes some error, but at least you see what really happens).

```
const TagsField = ({record, ...props}) => (
    <ArrayField source="images">
        {console.log("Record:")}
        {console.log(record)}
        <TextField source="image"/>
    </ArrayField>
)
... 
export const HouseList = (props) => (
<ListGuesser title="houses" {...props}>
    ....
    <NumberField source="price" label="Price (€)"/>
    <TagsField label="Images" source="images" sortable={false}>
    </TagsField>
    ....
```

Has someone an idea, what I did wrong over here?

**Even more details**

https://github.com/api-platform/admin/pull/299

Comment: Hey, thanks! This actually works for me and is a nicer solution than the ReferenceField, because there is no additional loading time involved. Maybe in your case it doesn't work because it's an array of images and not a single one?

Comment: Just checked the GitHub pull request.
"If it's an array of embeddeds, the previous behavior stays the same: objects are replaced by their IRI and references are used in FieldGuesser and InputGuesser."

Answer (score 0):

I've created the PR to add support for arrays of embeddeds: https://github.com/api-platform/admin/pull/302.

It will be in the next version (a patch one).